# editing 4k and 3840 × 2160 video with a Mac pro1,1

Tags: video, hardware, 4k

I just got a Panasonic Gh4 camera and recorded some 4k footage with it.

For editing I have a Mac pro1,1 (2007):

- Dual-Core Intel Xeon - 2,66 GHz
- NVIDIA GeForce 7300 GT - VRAM:32768 MB
- 15 GB memory

**I can´t even see the footage move correctly in order to see what I´ve got and start editing.**

I don´t know much about hardware and before I start spending money trying to upgrade my old computer I´d like to know if it is going to work. If I could see it in real time I could then create proxis and work with them. apparently only 512 mbts Cards are compatible with my computer, these are the ones I know about:

- Ati radeon HD 4870 512 mbts
- Gforce-gt 120 512 mbts
- Gforce 8800 gt 512 mbts
- and Ati radeon 5770 1 GB (but I´m not sure if this one will work)

**My question is:** will buying one of these and some more Ram make a difference?
I would truly apreciate some advice on this since I´m completely lost and my budget is very tight...

Thank you very much.

Comment: What software are you trying to use? I know, for example, that the latest FCP will not run on the GeForce 8800, though I think you're OK with the 5770. Not sure about the 4870, though. If you're using Premiere or something else, then I'm not sure.

Comment: Also, it's no clear that a MacPro 1,1 can run a recent OS, which would preclude you from running a recent version of something like FCPX.